# What is the english equivalant of Tamil saying 'pul thadukki bayilvan'?

Tags: meaning, phrases, equivalence

In Tamil, there is a saying

> புல் தடுக்கி பயில்வான் ( pul thadukki bayilvan )

that translates to something like below:

> A person who thinks himself as a wrestler but falling down even his
>   legs hit by grass.
>
> Or
>
> A person who is troubled by petty things

What is the equivalent word/phrase in english ?

Comment: In Texas: "All hat. No cattle" (but this is more about the contrast between how the person presents themselves and their actual merits)

Comment: Here's a good one.  "He couldn't escape from a wet paper sack."

Comment: The literal meaning of the Tamil phrase is useful, but please edit your question to include what kind of people this is used to describe, and give some examples of contexts and situations where it might be used. Sayings like this can differ enormously between languages, and without getting a good feel for the context, you might get suggestions that, although similar on the face of it, would be completely out of place in English in situations where the Tamil expression would be natural.

Answer (score -2):

A ***poseur***<sup>1</sup> is:

> someone who pretends to be something they are not, or to have qualities that they do not have:
>   *You look like a real poseur in your fancy sports car!*

<sup>1</sup>  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/poseur)

Often spelled informally/colloquially as ***poser***  (see [Urban Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/poseur):

> A poser is someone who tries to fit into a profile they aren't. People who try to give off the impression that they are one thing when they are really another. 
>   Also, a poser can be one who says they can do something that they can't.

But also this:

> Yes kids, that is how you spell poseur. No, I'm not trying to spell it some "fancy french way." Don't believe me? Let's go take a look at handy old Webster's:
>
> > Main Entry: po·seur
> >     Pronunciation: pO-'z&r
> >     Function: noun
> >     Etymology: French
> >     Date: 1872
> >     : *a person who pretends to be what he or she is not : an affected or insincere person*
>
> And there you have it. Still don't believe me?
>   Let's look up "poser":
>
> > Main Entry: pos·er
> >     Pronunciation: 'pO-z&r
> >     Function: noun
> >     Etymology: pose
> >     Date: 1793
> >     : a puzzling or baffling question
>
> Interesting.
>
> So, in closing, USE THE RIGHT WORD YOU IDIOTS. 
>   by Rilo June 27, 2003